# Antonym for "courtesy" in the sense of a polite custom?

Tags: nouns

For example, it's considered a courtesy for men to lower the toilet seat if they share a bathroom with women. In chess and many other games, it's considered a courtesy to resign once you've reached a practically unwinnable position instead of dragging the game out until the end, hoping for your opponent to stumble.

I'm looking for a word for a behavior similar in scope but intentionally rude. Something that would describe, say, ignoring messages from a friend, or tipping significantly below the standard rate at a restaurant when the service was fine, or the opposite of the examples in the first paragraph. *Faux pas* came to mind, but it suggests ignorance, not purposeful rudeness.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[Discourtesy](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/discourtesy) is a perfectly valid word. The first definition at that link is simply *rudeness*. Collins also give *bad manners* as a definition - that's another term that would work for you.

Comment: Indeed the antonyms provided by thesaurus.com for courtesy are discourtesy and rudeness.